# Email dynamically loaded content of jsp in HTML Formatted

Tags: java, jsp

In my application, user confirms and a jsp page is loaded with confirmation details. I need to email that confirmation.jsp page in the same format.

I tried doing it as below:

In JSP page, surrounded the Body with `<div id='content'>`
and then through a load function, sent the contents of the page through request paramater:

```
function load(){
    document.getElementById("emailbody").value=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
}
```

But the issue is, the page format has changed and it is not in a HTML format (not at all in readable format).

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should try sending mail on server side in a background thread so that your jsp rendering is not delayed. There are useful server side temlating engines like velocity which can help you achieve your tarhet html and would be easy to send then.